# Excel Add-in to call subroutine from ActiveWorkbook

Tags: vba, excel

I created an Add-In that adds a sheet to a Workbook and imports multiple modules. I would then like for the Add-in to run a Subroutine that is now in Active Workbook. This is what I have so far, and I'm getting Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

What is the correct syntax (if it can even be done). Thanks.

```
' Class name is EventClassModule
Public WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    If Wb.Name = "Just To Test.xls" Then
        Wb.Sheets.Add Type:="C:\TestGLPage.xls"
    fname = Dir("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BAS\*.*", vbNormal)
    While fname <> ""
       If Right(fname, 3) = "frm" Or Right(fname, 3) = "bas" Or Right(fname, 3) = "cls" Then
       ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BAS\" & fname
       End If
       fname = Dir()  'get the next file
    Wend
    Call Application.Workbooks("Just To Test.xls").starter
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA is **not** a dynamic language. When you alter the code or the names of code objects at runtime VBA has to recompile those modules before the changes can be accessed. You may find breakpoints don't work properly after you've made such changes as well.

This recompilation happens automatically and immediately, but is not accessible from code that is already executing. You need to get Excel to re-enter the VBA code.

You may be able to get away with using Application.Run, but I would probably use Application.OnTime to be safer if you don't need starter to be a blocking call (which appears to be the case in your example code).

Just for clarity, when calling a subroutine using Application.Run or Application.OnTime you cannot qualify it using the module name. You can however qualify it using the workbook's name using bang syntax. Eg. `Application.Run "Book1.xlsx!SubNameToBeCalled"`

## Example

I created a blank workbook
I created two modules

#### Imported

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    MsgBox "Test!"
End Sub
```

#### Main

```
Public Sub Run()
  ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\Temp\Imported.bas"
  ' Showing how to do it with Run
  Application.Run ThisWorkbook.Name & "!RunMe"
  ' Showing the safer way with OnTime
  Application.OnTime Now, ThisWorkbook.Name & "!RunMe"
End Sub
```

I then exported the "Imported" module to "C:\Temp\Imported.bas" and removed it from the project.

Comment: Thank you. I used OnTime and it works. Can you please explain to me why OnTime is a better way to go. I've never used OnTime, and I would love to learn.

Comment: Run calls a macro as part of the current execution, and returns a value. OnTime schedules a macro to be run at a specified time. By using OnTime with the current time we tell Excel to run the macro as soon as reasonably possible. Because of this, control is returned to Excel, and it is allowed to do any work it needs to before it calls the macro. Where as Application.Run does not necessarily give Excel that chance.